# Add Alt attribute from value of scr name in a whole website in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add Alt tag example. Here's my code:

```
<img src="www.abcs.com/images/logo.png">
```

And I want something like this in each and every image tag:

```
<img src ="www.abcs.com/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

Comment: You want to add the alt tag with jQuery? may I ask why? You could just to this in the HTML. And why would you want multiple alt tags containing the same text? Alt tags are meant to differentiate the images for SEO purposes. Having the same alt tag makes them practically unfindable.

Comment: i need to add different text for all Alt tag just split text form img src and need to insert in whole website image tag

Comment: If it is for SEO purpose, than adding ALT via Javascript won't help to improve quality of pages. Spider simple won't see it. You have to do it on server-side.

Comment: you are absolute right this is for SEO purpose

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery use `.attr()` method:

```
$('img').attr('alt', function(){
    var src = this.src.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    return src;
});
```

`.attr()` method accepts first arg as a property of element and second arg can be either a string or a function. In this case you can dynamically apply the alt attribute to all the images available on the page and in the callback function of attr you have to `return` the value.

Comment: Isn't this question is better to ask the OP? May be OP has stuck at a situation where he might not be able to do the things manually when someone has more than 400*+ images in an application.

Comment: I've deleted question. I agree, it should go to OP.

Comment: _What is the purpose of doing this on client-side?_   to answer it: Cost efficient.

Comment: yes, however if the purpose to index (by google) 'alt' value - than client side is not a way to go.

Comment: Well it depends on the application. Whether it is available to world or just for the users in an organization if the case is 2nd one then there is not an issue.

Comment: @PrinceSaini then manually go and change it because js is not for SEO.